# JAX-RS GROUP Validation not recognized by Swagger on JAX-RS Version 1.5.12

Tags: java, validation, jax-rs

I have a scenario where a property has a different validation applied depending on end-point. This is done via "groups" (code example below & reference to dropwizard doc: http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.3/docs/manual/validation.html#validated). I implemented the DropWizard validations but the Swagger does not recognizing the "groups" and therefore doesn't provided correct model description. In addition Swagger doesn't seem to have any annotations that would accomplish the scenario. Can you please help? Thank you.

---

```
public interface Version1FirstName { }

public interface Version2FirstName { }

class Person {
 @NotEmpty(groups = Version1FirstName .class)
 @Length(max = 5, groups = Version2FirstName .class)
 private firstName;
 private lastName;
}

@POST
@Path("/v1")
public void addName(@Validated(Version1FirstName.class) Person person) {}

@POST
@Path("/v2")
public void retriveName(@Validated({Version2FirstName.class,
                                    Version1FirstName.class}) Person person) {}
```